# Pandas dataframe has zero elements after using dropna()

Tags: python, pandas

My `dataframe` has zero elements after I use `dropna()` on a 2-dimensional array:

[image: excel]

```
data = pd.read_excel('/file.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', engine='openpyxl').iloc[0:, 0:].astype(float).dropna().values.flatten()

data
array([], dtype=float64)
```

However `dropna()` works perfectly fine on a 1-dimensional array and the `NaNs` get cleared out.

What could be something wrong I'm doing?

Comment: What statement you're using to drop null? the fourth column is null and if you have NOT specified the axis, rows with any null value will get deleted. That is probably what has happened.

Comment: @Naveed dropna() end of line in my code

Comment: you need to specify the axis=1, so only column get dropped, if that is what you're looking for

Comment: my NaNs are on each row. Would that be sufficient to add the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dropna function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) defaults to `axis=0`, as per the documentation:

> Determine if rows or columns which contain missing values are removed.
>
> - 0, or ‘index’ : Drop rows which contain missing values.
> - 1, or ‘columns’ : Drop columns which contain missing value.

So, your code becomes:

```py
data = pd.read_excel('/file.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', engine='openpyxl').iloc[0:, 0:].astype(float).dropna(axis=1).values.flatten()
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the `.dropna()` removes the entire selected axis, speaking of axis, the default axis is also set to be rows. Maybe that's not what you want?

If you then in each rows have a NaN value, then all of the rows is going to be droped.

To fix this you can specify it like this

```
.dropna(axis=1)
```